# html <ruby> tag text not aligned with <rt> text in android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

In an android **WebView** I have vertical text with ruby tags with css to make the body reflow like pages

This is the activity code, it loads the text.html file into a **WebView**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/text.html")
    }
}
```

text.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body style="writing-mode: vertical-rl; width: 100vw; column-width: 100vh; margin: 0">
<p>
    <ruby>漢字<rt>かんじ</rt></ruby>
    <ruby>漢字<rt>かんじ</rt></ruby>
    <ruby>漢字<rt>かんじ</rt></ruby>
    ... x 400
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is an image of what this produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TUf5.jpg)
The ruby tags are getting cropped and are not reflowing properly.

The smaller characters are supposed to be next to the larger ones. According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) the ruby tag is supported in android WebView.

I could not find any mention of this effect anywhere.
I have not been able to recreate this error in a chrome webview. What I mean to say is with the same css in chrome, the entire ruby tag reflows together.

Is this in fact a bug?
Or are there other css rules I can use to make the ruby display properly?

Comment: I think OP added additional quote by accident. `vertical-rl` but not `"vertical-rl"`

Comment: Yeah, I just changed that. It's not supposed to be a snippet though because I haven't found this to be a problem on chrome, only in android webview